# Data from form doesn't save at database ( can't validate )

Tags: django, validation, model

When I try to add some content with my post form I always have an validation error
I don't correctly understand how to use checkbox validation.
All the data prints to the console with csrf token, but can't save to db.

models.py

```
class Film(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField('Название фильма', max_length=255)
        #slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=55)
        description = models.TextField('Описание фильма', null=True)
        main_image = models.ImageField('Постер', upload_to='images/film_poster')
        image1 = models.ImageField('Первое изображение', upload_to='images/')
        image2 = models.ImageField('Второе изображение', upload_to='images/')
        image3 = models.ImageField('Третее изображение', upload_to='images/')
        image4 = models.ImageField('Четвёртое изображение', upload_to='images/')
        image5 = models.ImageField('Пятое изображение', upload_to='images/')
        trailer_link = models.URLField('Ссылка на трейлер')
        two_d = models.BooleanField('2Д',default=False)
        three_d = models.BooleanField('3Д',default=False)
        i_max = models.BooleanField('I_MAX', default=False)
        duration = models.CharField('Длительность фильма', max_length=55)
        first_night = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата премьеры', null=True)
```

There is my view's:
views.py

```
def film_page(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FilmForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('film_list')
        else:
            error = 'error'
    form = FilmForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }
    return render(request, 'adminLte/film/film_page.html', data)
```

That's mine Html-file

```
{% extends 'adminLte/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
    <div class="features flex-fill">
        <div class="row m-3">
            <div class="container">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="FilmNameInput"><h4>Нfilm name</h4></label>
                        {{ form.title }} **(title for example)**
                    </div>
                    <div class="container my-5">
                        <button class="btn-success" type="submit"></button>
                    </div>
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Film
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, DateInput, FileInput,URLInput, CheckboxInput, Textarea


class FilmForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'main_image', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'trailer_link',
                  'two_d', 'three_d', 'i_max', 'duration', 'first_night']


        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Введите название фильма',
                'id': 'FilmNameInput',
            }),
            

        }
```

So, actually I don't know what to do

Comment: Did you check if the form is valid with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your view is handling form errors incorrectly. Try following [Django's example of a form view:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-view)

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

The key here is that if the form is not valid, it will continue on to the line that renders the template with the same form that was checked for errors. Then the errors can be rendered the template and you will likely see what it is complaining about. In your code you were creating a new empty form that was replacing the one that had the errors so you would never see form errors.

Also in the template you need to render the errors for the form. I would use [Django's example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#the-template) to render the form in the template first:

```html
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then once you have it working, you can try customizing it some more. If you still have trouble getting it working, I would suggest using a debugger to step through your code so you can learn more about how it works.